# Store USB print jobs on Debian

Tags: debian, printing

I have an industrial device that now prints via USB to a thermal printer.

I need to replace the thermal printer with a Debian based single-board computer and to be able to store the print jobs as text files within the SBC file system. But I have no idea where to start from.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

UPDATE - Once stored, the text (not PDF) files will be processed by a ruby application running on the SBC.

The industrial device doesn't have any UI, it's connected to the printer, and when needed it prints. So if the SBC looks like a printer, I guess there are more chances everything works as expected. However, the SBC may listen to the USB port and read the input. At the end of the day, I care more to get the job done than craeting a virtual printer.

Hope the update clarifies what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Edit question to make clear: Are you thinking of storing PDFs, of what would otherwise have been printed? Does this new device have to look like a printer (from the perspective of another device)?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for your comment. I hope now my goal is clear.

Comment: Is the SBC also have the print driver to format print for printer. It used to be printers had some limited formatting but software then created codes for that formatting. And in other cases you may not want any printer formatting and have to use a raw printer driver that just passes all the details. Years ago we used Basic to download data and ZPL to format labels for Zebra printer. Probably like this now: https://qz.io/wiki/Setting-Up-A-Raw-Printer-in-Ubuntu-Linux and https://github.com/qzind/tray

Comment: Ideally, the solution should work without drivers. Thanks